# Configure NGINX reverse proxy to verify client certificate custom field

Tags: nginx, client-certificate

I would like to verify a client certificate "custom" field directly with NGINX before returning it to the actual page.

As I understand from here: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client 
it's easily achievable for fields like subject DN, issuer DN , client searial, end date etc
But is there a way to validate a custome field my CA is appending to the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

By the way [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) works, **nginx** does not verify any of those data. It just verifies that the certificate is signed (directly or through intermediate certificates) by a trusted CA. It is the CA job to verify those data. Usually the last part of the subject DN (the CN or emailAddress part) is somehow verified.

**nginx** is able to extract some standard extensions from the certificate, but if you want to read the non standard ones you need to add the whole certificate as a header and send it to your application with something like:

```
proxy_set_header X-Client-Cert $ssl_client_escaped_cert
```

Comment: Thx Piotr for your answer. So if i have my own private CA i can ”group” my users withian intermediate CA  but let say i need to move to a public CA this would mean everyone with a valid certificate signed by the same Public CA would pass the nginx certificate control or there’s another way to verify a group of certificates?